# What are the pros and cons of common modulation techniques?

Tags: modulation, demodulation

What are the pros and cons of commonly used modulation techniques? Why is one preferred over another in a given situation? Why do so many exist? Are some better at resisting noise, travelling long distances, packing more data?

Analog

- Amplitude modulation
- Frequency modulation
- Phase modulation

Digital

- Phase shift keying
- Frequency shift keying
- Amplitude shift keying
- Quadrature amplitude modulation
- Orthogonal frequency division modulation
- Direct sequence spread spectrum

*And any other major ones I missed in the list above